# Kiosk - no internet

Tags: pdf, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I want to open a PDF local file in a kiosk mode on startup. I'm struggling with a basic PDF viewer like SumatraPDF now and even GitHub discussions aren't giving me answers. Can anyone here help me? I just want to open my PDF full screen on startup automatically without any task or scroll bars (it's on a touchscreen).

I've tried changing the settings with Sumatra, I've tried Edge kiosk mode, but with a local PDF, even on kiosk it opens the file with the toolbar/taskbar visible. Do I have to go into some kind of task or application code through backend Windows?

Tried command line but it merely opens an application, does not implement fullscreen upon launch.

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard setting within PDF files, which you can set like this:

`cpdf -set-page-mode FullScreen in.pdf -o out.pdf`

Of course, you will have to verify your PDF viewer obeys this.

Comment: I'm sorry how is this "entered" into the pdf's settings? Where do I enter this? Thanks.

Comment: It's a command line command which uses the `cpdf` program from https://community.coherentpdf.com/ to alter the PDF file, by setting an internal flag in the file.

Comment: It's part of the PDF ISO standard, not an "Acrobat directive". Now, of course, that doesn't mean that other viewers support it, as you point out.

Answer (score 0):

For SumatraPDF the -fullscreen switch needs to be between exe and pdf like so

```
"C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -fullscreen "C:\Apps\test 2.pdf"
```

It should look like (ignore my personal toolbar)

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/12754913/234652350-3f56b108-7b72-4a39-bac5-02fea9d03158.png]  [image]

For MsEdge it is similar between exe and PDF where you need to add `#toolbar=0` onto the filename.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --kiosk --no-first-run --edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen "file:///C:/Apps/test 2.pdf#toolbar=0"
```

[image]

Follow MS instructions for adding to start-up in 10 / 11 it should be the same. HOWEVER beware It would then block users normal view of start-up desktop.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/add-an-app-to-run-automatically-at-startup-in-windows-10-150da165-dcd9-7230-517b-cf3c295d89dd

[image]